# Adjust Padding of Shiny Table Using css

Tags: css, r, shiny

Let's say I want to reduce the padding between the left edge of the screen and the first column to maximize real estate on an iPhone. Here's the table:

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = "styles.css",
  
  mainPanel(
    align = "left",
    reactableOutput("table")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- renderReactable({
    reactable(iris,
              fullWidth = FALSE
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And styles.css is:

```
.container-fluid {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}
```

This does not work. However, if I use Chrome Inspector to look at the gap, I can manually set `padding-left: 0` and the gap narrows.

[image]

How do I narrow the gap from within R/Shiny//css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in the inspector in the sources tab if the file is being correctly included. If it still does not work check if there are errors in your css file, that might be preventing the stylesheet from working. Finally, you might have to set the style inline or in the style tag. If you are using Bootstrap then you can use the ml-0 class in the container.